# access the two neighbors of an element in a list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement Wolfram’s elementary cellular automaton (rule 30) in haskell.

Result for `./wolfram 10` :

```
          *          
         ***         
        **  *        
       ** ****       
      **  *   *      
     ** **** ***     
    **  *    *  *    
   ** ****  ******   
  **  *   ***     *  
 ** **** **  *   ***
```

To start, I generate this list : `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` where 0 is `' '` and 1 is `'*'`.

Passing this list to the function `genNextLine :: [Int] -> [Int]` will generate the next list.

For a given element, the next element is determined by its two neighbors (example : `[0, 1, 1]` will generate a `1`).

I can iterate through the list element by element like this :

```
genNextLine :: [Int] -> [Int]
genNextLine (x : xs) = ...
```

But how can I iterate through the list by accessing elements `x - 1`, `x`, `x + 1` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pattern matching for prefixes of any length you want:

```hs
genNextLine :: [Int] -> [Int]
genNextLine (x1:x2:x3:xs) = (doSomethingWith x1 x2 x3):(getNextLine $ (x2:x3:xs))
genNextLine xs = xs
```

Btw, what about using `zipWith3`?

```hs
genNextLine :: [Int] -> [Int]
genNextLine (x1:x2:xs) = zipWith3 doSomethingWith (x1:x2:xs) (x2:xs) xs
```